# How to send DM messages after triggering comand Dsharp+

Tags: dsharp+

I'm making a Discord bot and i'm in trouble. Idk how to send direct message after triggering command by user, i tried to use RequireDirectMessage, but after this command just became inactive, i couldn't trigger it neither in discord Guild nor in direct message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a DM channel and then send a message to that channel like this

```
[Command("senddm"]
public async Task SendDMExample(CommandContext ctx)
{
    var DMChannel = await ctx.Member.CreateDmChannelAsync();
    await DMChannel.SendMessageAsync("WhateverYouAreSending");
}
```